# Read a array from a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file with an array written in it, like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

How can I read it and get the array in a variable with python? So far what happens is that I just get the string.

```
def get_data():
     myfile = open('random_array.txt', 'r')
     data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
     return data
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there is only one array with this exact format in the file?

Comment: This question might help you to get the list from the string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list-in-python

Comment: Tobias, yes it is. It will always be the same format.With only one Array showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the format is always like that, one way is to use `json.loads`:

```
>>> s = "[1,2,3,4]"
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(s)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This has the advantage that you can use any space between the commas, you can use floats and ints in the text, and so on.

So, in your case you could do this:

```
import json

def get_data():
    with open("random_array.txt", "r") as f:
        return json.load(f)
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems to do what I want, and a simpe solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case it is better to use the `json` module, as it seems your array uses the same format, but in general you can do something like this:

```
def get_data(filename):
     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [int(x) for x in f.read().strip('[]\n').split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
def get_data():
    myfile = open('random_array.txt', 'r')
    data = myfile.read().strip()
    data = data[1:len(data)-1]
    splitted = data.split(", ")
    return splitted
```

This removes the beginning and trailing "[]" and then splits the string on each `", "`, leaving you with an array of strings that are exactly the numbers.

Comment: But with this solution you wont treat the numbers as int, everything will be considered as string, right?

Comment: @GonacFaria yes that's true, but for the simple sake of parsing the data, that should be enough. You could then convert the individual elements of the array via `int(data[i])`. But yes indeed, the json-parser method is more elegant.

Comment: Indeed it is more elegant and a lot simplier. I didn't want to parse the string, but looking for a way to interpreter it.